# Merge two objects with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, merge

I need to merge 2 objects in angularJS
Im trying with angular.merge(obj1, obj2), but that's not what I expected

First object

```
 // obj1
{
  "0": {
    "name": "340.jpg",
    "bytes": 21955,
    "link": "340.jpg?dl=0",
    "icon": "page_white_picture.png"
  },

  "1": {
    "name": "341.pdf",
    "bytes": 3394,
    "link": "340.pdf?dl=0",
    "icon": "page_white_acrobat.png"

  }
```

Second Object

```
// obj2
{
  "id_pro": "70",
  "nuevo": "true",
  "fecha_ser": "2017-10-18"
}
```

Expected result

```
// Merged
{

  "0": {
    "name": "340.jpg",
    "bytes": 21955,
    "link": "340.jpg?dl=0",
    "icon": "icons64/page_white_picture.png",

    "id_pro": "70",
    "nuevo": "true",
    "fecha_ser": "2017-10-18"
  },

  "1": {
    "name": "341.pdf",
    "bytes": 3394,
    "link": "340.pdf?dl=0",
    "icon": "page_white_acrobat.png",

    "id_pro": "70",
    "nuevo": "true",
    "fecha_ser": "2017-10-18"

  }

}
```

Add the second object exactly in each group of first object.

Is possible with angular.merge or i need a own function ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `native` javascript.

One of the solutions includes `forEach` method in combination with `Object.assign` in order to **merge** the properties.

```js
let obj={
  "0": {
    "name": "340.jpg",
    "bytes": 21955,
    "link": "340.jpg?dl=0",
    "icon": "page_white_picture.png"
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "341.pdf",
    "bytes": 3394,
    "link": "340.pdf?dl=0",
    "icon": "page_white_acrobat.png"

  }
};
let second={
  "id_pro": "70",
  "nuevo": "true",
  "fecha_ser": "2017-10-18"
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
  Object.assign(obj[key],second);
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do an iteration on first object

```
for(var i in obj1) {
    angular.merge(obj1[i], obj2);
}
```

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you Keming

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that there are many ways to iterate the object. Since you're working with AngularJS anyway, you can use the Angular helper method:

```
angular.forEach(obj1, function(obj) {
    angular.merge(obj, obj2);
});
```